# How to dynamically create and play audio with "AudioContext" in a web browser (using PyScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, pyscript

Using the javascript [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) interface I want to create an Audiostream that is playing a dynamically created 1-second long waveform continuously. That waveform is supposed to be updated when I change a slider on the html page etc.

So basically I want to feed in a vector containing 44100 floats that represents that 1-second long waveform.

So far I have

```
const audio = new AudioContext({
  latencyHint: "interactive",
  sampleRate: 44100,
});
```

but I am not sure how to apply that vector/list/data structure with my actual waveform.

Hint: I want to add audio to this [PyScript](https://realpython.com/pyscript-python-in-browser/#combining-the-power-of-python-and-javascript-libraries) example.

Comment: I'm not confident if I truly understood your question / is it solvable with a simple loop like I did. If I misunderstood I'm happy to delete my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This example might help you, it generates a random float array and plays that. I think. You can click "go" multiple times to generate a new wave.

**WARNING: BE CAREFUL WITH THE VOLUME IF YOU RUN THIS. IT CAN BE DANGEROUSLY LOUD!**

```js
function makeWave(audioContext) {
  const floats = []
  for (let i = 44000;i--;) floats.push(Math.random()*2 - 1)
  console.log("New waveform done")

  const sineTerms = new Float32Array(floats)
  const cosineTerms = new Float32Array(sineTerms.length)
  const customWaveform = audioContext.createPeriodicWave(cosineTerms, sineTerms)
  return customWaveform
}

let audioCtx, oscillator, gain, started = false
document.querySelector("#on").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Initialize only once
  if (!gain) {
    audioCtx = new AudioContext() // Controls speakers
    gain = audioCtx.createGain() // Controls volume
    oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator() // Controls frequency

    gain.connect(audioCtx.destination) // connect gain node to speakers

    oscillator.connect(gain) // connect oscillator to gain
    oscillator.start()
  }

  const customWaveform = makeWave(audioCtx)
  oscillator.setPeriodicWave(customWaveform)
  gain.gain.value = 0.02 // ☠☠ CAREFUL WITH VOLUME ☠☠
})

document.querySelector("#off").addEventListener("click", () => {
  gain.gain.value = 0
})
```

```html
<b>SET VOLUME VERY LOW BEFORE TEST</b>
<button id="on">GO</button>
<button id="off">STOP</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is very close to what I want. But instead of an oscillator with a precise defined frequency I want to play my own waveform (noise) which might be represented with an array of values. It is not an oscillator. Not a constant frequency, but an arbitrary waveform. How can I "set" this arbitrary 1-second long waveform to be played over and over (until I click "stop")?

Comment: @Alex Hmm, how about now - this thing is far simpler creating a large array of floats and basically tries to play that. Based completely on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createPeriodicWave#examples

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, I tried to use that with my python code that generates a waveform, but when I try to open that html page it loads forever. I have no idea how to debug this

Comment: Here is my file "audio.js": https://codeshare.io/8pw8wZ

Comment: @Alex That code is missing a few pieces; such as where is the `waveform` variable coming from and what calls the `updateAudio` function. Could I see a GitHub repo or something with more code? I'm github.com/Req Oh and also, an `AudioContext` also can't be created on page load. Make a test page with nothing but `<script>new AudioContext()</script>` and you will get in the dev console: `The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page`

Comment: I have created the following repo: https://github.com/alex4200/PyScriptExample

Comment: @Alex Nice! Let's continue the discussion at https://github.com/alex4200/PyScriptExample/issues/1